# Solving exponential equations with different bases

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I solve these exponential equations in terms of $x$ despite they have different bases?

Equation to solve:  $$3^{x-2}=-2^{x-1}+3.$$

Comment: By trial and error, $x=2$ is a solution. Can you find a way of showing that it is the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that X=2 is a solution (as Dylan pointed out). Both functions are monotonously increasing, so rewriting it as $3^{X-2}+2^{X-1}=3$ makes it obvious that the left side is a monotonously increasing function of X, therefore That is the only solution.